# Error when using hardhat but changes made successfully onto smart contract, was able to see changes on etherscan

Tags: solidity, ether, hardhat, sepolia

```
const [signer] = await ethers.getSigners();

const contractAddress = 'address...';

const contractABI = ["abi..."];

const existingContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

await existingContract.store(3)
const favoriteNumber = await existingContract.retrieve();
console.log(favoriteNumber);
```

My code works successfully when I run it on the hardhat network. But when i try it with the sepolia network, I can an error. But I then check on etherscan and the changes were made successfully. Why am I getting the error? This error applies to deploying, interacting,

````
C:\Users\Joe\OneDrive\Documents\blockchain\part-6-hardhat\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:656
            error = new TypeError(message);
                    ^
TypeError: yParity mismatch (argument="signature", value={ "accessList": [  ], "blockHash": null, "blockNumber": null, "chainId": "0xaa36a7", "from": "0x4bb1e60520bb945e2d7b4909812dcdfd0492436f", "gas": "0x5d68", "gasPrice": "0xdded1b732", "hash": "0xad420d9a6bb7f09649dfdbfba045637853220c5a45c30e6ecf90fdcb1225ffe9", "input": "0x6057361d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003", "maxFeePerGas": "0xdded1b732", "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "0x59682f00", "nonce": "0x22", "r": "0x2013d891defa922072e537046b5c55808bc32c5028f6bd98623cbfd4ba863d67", "s": "0xf6a48497ae9277819dbaeee50479ae809decd0d759cb65c44247f615ae7e1f3", "to": "0x4a68ec1d36af2b193b27e53cc418b0705ca08adb", "transactionIndex": null, "type": "0x2", "v": "0x1", "value": "0x0", "yParity": "0x1" }, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.4.0)
    at makeError (C:\Users\Joe\OneDrive\Documents\blockchain\part-6-hardhat\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:656:21)
    at assert (C:\Users\Joe\OneDrive\Documents\blockchain\part-6-hardhat\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:680:25)
    at assertArgument (C:\Users\Joe\OneDrive\Documents\blockchain\part-6-hardhat\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:692:5)
    at assertError (C:\Users\Joe\OneDrive\Documents\blockchain\part-6-hardhat\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\crypto\signature.ts:277:27)
    at Function.from (C:\Users\Joe\OneDrive\Documents\blockchain\part-6-hardhat\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\crypto\signature.ts:357:9)
    at formatTransactionResponse (C:\Users\Joe\OneDrive\Documents\blockchain\part-6-hardhat\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\ethers-utils.ts:263:34)
    at HardhatEthersProvider.getTransaction (C:\Users\Joe\OneDrive\Documents\blockchain\part-6-hardhat\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\hardhat-ethers-provider.ts:275:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at checkTx (C:\Users\Joe\OneDrive\Documents\blockchain\part-6-hardhat\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\signers.ts:135:26)
error Command failed with exit code 1.```
````

Answer (score 1):

Solved: Just updated my ethers version to 6.6.4